# PID control with PIC microcontroller

Tags: battery-charging, pic, c, programming, pid-controller

I'm relatively new in C program ( I'm using MPLAB X IDE XC8 ), and first time trying to make a PID control, using a PIC16F15223

This is what I want to make:

- The pic has an analog input that reads a SHUNT resistor. This will oscillate between 0-3V, so in the code between 0-615.
- The pic has a PWM output with a fixed frequency of 100hz, the duty cycle will oscillate between 0% and 100%.
- This is for controlling the current charge of a battery ( lead-acid ). The control is made with two SCRs making a full bridge rectifier ( with the transformer with a center tap ), the gate of the SCRs its controlled by a MOC3021 ( optocoupler ), and the MOC3021 its controlled by the PWM output of the PIC16F15223.
- I'm having troubles with the code in C. Firstly because I never made a PID control, and then because I search some of them in the internet but I dont know how to implement them.
- I read the current and store it in an INT variable called measured_current. Then I put it in the calculate_PID program, and that return's me a value. So that value it's the current that I will have to send as a PWM signal until it reaches a SET POINT, and then it will maintain this current to work as a constant current charge. The problem it's that I don't know how to turn this output value of the pid as a pwm duty cycle. In fact I'm not sure that the PID code its ok, because it was taked from a general PID code from internet...
  I let you the code and schematic:

```
            current_pid = calculatePID(measured_current);
            
            if (current_pid>0)
            {
                
            }
            else if (current_pid<0)
            {
                
            }
            else if (current_pid==0)
            {
                
            }
```

```
#include <stdint.h>

// Variables del control PID
double kp = 1.0;  // Ganancia proporcional
double ki = 0.5;  // Ganancia integral
double kd = 0.2;  // Ganancia derivada
double setPoint = 0;  // Valor deseado

double error = 0.0; 
double prevError = 0.0;
double integral = 0.0;
double derivative = 0.0;  

double calculatePID(double inputValue) {
    error = setPoint - inputValue;
    
    double proportional = kp * error;
    
    integral += ki * error;
    
    derivative = kd * (error - prevError);
    prevError = error;
    
    double output = proportional + integral + derivative;
    
    return output;
}
```

[image]

The PWM duty cycle can be calculated as:
[image]
Where in PWM3DCL store the 2 less significative bits and PWM3DCH the remaining ones.
I'm using PR2=155.

Comment: The first issue is your are using pwm for phase control. That probably won’t work well for you. You need to time the scr trigger pulse from mains zero crossing. Get that working first. Rather than using full PID at first, just use simple proportional control with a fixed sample time. Then work in some integral. You may not need the derivative term. Make sure you bounds check all inputs and outputs!

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot to say that, i have a working zero crossing detector. But i was thinking that i dont need that because one terminal of the thyristor output of the optocoupler is connected to the battery +, that its charging with a full wave rectifier signal. But i dont know if this its correct

Comment: About adding a PID, really i dont know how to implement this with another type of control, thats why i choose PID, the project I'm doing doesn't needs to be very sophisticated, as you see, im charging the battery with a 100hz pulsating signal... I think that my doubt its basically how to convert from the current signal that im reading into a percentage for the duty cycle of the PWM

Comment: As an initial guess you could look at the range of your input (10-bit ADC gives you 0-1023) and scale that to the range of your output (4 x (PR2 + 1) == 424), so divide your PID output by 2.4, limit it to a range of 1 to 423, and feed that to your PWM. After that you can tune your kp, ki & kd to get the response you're looking for from the PID.

Comment: Thats smart... So supose that i did that, and my new PWM number its 300. In binary 100101100. I have to substract the last two 0 for the register PWM3DCL. For this i can do it in this way? -> PWM3DCL=PWM_Number<<7, and then for the PWM3DCH register like this-> PWM3DCH=PWM_number>>2. This is okay?

Comment: Why is your question title in ALL CAPS? Everyone else uses lower case?

Comment: Unless your trigger is synchronised with the mains, you’ll get random on time from the scrs. Remember scrs require the current to drop below a given value in order to turn off. You require phase control, not pwm.

Comment: Yes those shifts should work fine. You could also consider just building that "2.4" factor into your kp, ki & kd to avoid having the extra scaling step at the end, but don't forget to still apply the 1 to 423 range limit either way.

Comment: You should also add a limiting value for the integral.

Comment: How can i do that in the integral or kp, ki & kd?

Comment: @samuel - Declare a variable called il and set it to the limit.  Then, after the line "integral += ki * error", add the lines "if (integral > il) integral = il;"